# what can I do to install Open-CV library ? I'm having a conflict problem as shown in the picture

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ71d.png)

[image]**strong text**

I am working on a little image processing project (face recognition) using Anaconda Spyder .The problem is that I am not able to install the open CV library.What do you recommend ?

Comment: Please do not post text as pictures. You can copy/paste text from the console and then add the text here.

Comment: always put code, data and error mesage as text, not image.

Comment: did you try to use `pip` to install it ? But it has different name `pip install opencv-python`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to review here. "pip" Because you can load many libraries with pip.

Answer (score 0):

I have switched to PyCharm instead of anaconda and it works.My guess is that it was something about setting path variables.